# Do object-src and base-uri bypasses still work on Content-Security-Policies?

Tags: xss, content-security-policy, header

I'm assessing the security level of a webapp and one of the test cases is the CSP header. I always use the [Google CSP evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/) to assess the header. Let's consider the following CSP header:

```
Content-Security-Policy:
img-src 'self' https://example.com data: www.google-analytics.com;  
object-src 'self' https://example.com data:; 
script-src 'self' https://example.com www.google-analytics.com;
```

The evaluator states that there are two high severity findings; one for allowing the data attribute for an object element; other one for missing the base-uri directive. So I thought: "Hey, that's great, then maybe we can still exploit XSS by bypassing the CSP."

However, in my local webserver set-up with the CSP header above, the CSP policy still triggers a violation when injecting object elements with a data attribute or a base element. I'm rendering a page which echoes the user input from a query string right into the page unescaped.

I've read some articles about people succeeding in bypassing CSP with object elements and base-uri's like these:

```
<object data="data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgxKTwvc2NyaXB0Pg=="></object>
<base href="data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgxKTwvc2NyaXB0Pg==" />
```

Result:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).
```

The CSP policy blocks these payloads as it states that inline scripts are not allowed. Even with a barebone CSP like `default-src 'self'` the violation still triggers.

1. Has something changed over time or am I just doing it wrong?
2. Are data attributes URI's etc. always seen as inline scripts?
3. How 'high' are these findings then? Only setting 'unsafe-inline' will make the bypasses work, but that completely makes the bypass useless, because then you can inject script tags whatsoever.